# Invalid keyword at beginning of an expression(lolcode)

Tags: lolcode

I just started using LOLCODE. I tried making a program that tests if a input is a NUMBR but I get the error Invalid keyword at beginning of an expression on line 13 (`IM OUTTA YR LOOP`).
Hese is my code. Please help. Thanks.

```
I HAS A VARIABLE 
I HAS A ITERATOR ITZ 0
I HAS A TRUTH
IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR ITERATOR WILE DIFFRINT TRUTH AN "WIN"
    VISIBLE "GIMMEH NUMBR"
    GIMMEH VARIABLE
    VARIABLE IS NOW A NUMBR, O RLY?
        YA RLY
            I HAS A TRUTH ITZ "FAIL"
            GTFO
        NO WAI
            VISIBLE "HOW U FAIL SIMPL INSTUCTINS"
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `OIC` at the end of your if statement.

```
VARIABLE IS NOW A NUMBR, O RLY?
    YA RLY
        I HAS A TRUTH ITZ "FAIL"
        GTFO
    NO WAI
        VISIBLE "HOW U FAIL SIMPL INSTUCTINS"
OIC
```

See : https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md#if-then